# How to change view when clicking on a UITabBar via segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm new to segue in Xcode and have trouble understanding how UITabbar works.

[image]

Essentially as long as I stay within the first tab "Wellbeing", I should be able to see three menu items.  Each menu item should show a different view.

I'm a bit lost how I can load a different view according to the menu item selection.  Theoretically, I could create just another two views like "Wellbeing" with a similar Menu bar. As I click around in the menu bar I would divert the view to those views.

But I'm not sure how to achieve this via segue. An advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use containerViews inside that view and set the one you want to show first when the view appears like `view.bringSubview(toFront: preferredFirstView)`and sent the rest to the back like `view.sendSubview(toBack: otherViews)` then when those buttons are selected reverse them however they are needed.

Comment: Interesting idea. And I still could design each view separately in IB, and load them up into the visible view this way...Doesn't feel like this is the official way of achieving this, but still a good way. Can you show me some code as answer please?

Comment: added answer and yes each containerView has an embedded ViewController that you make a whole new ViewController class for. I personally prefer this one a tab bar controller because i like setting the colors of all my buttons based on the contents of the view and it always returns nil with tabbarController

Answer (score 0):

Add ContainerViews to the view within the individual
tab.  Make `@IBOutlets` for each containerView. Then set your preferred view at load to visible like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.bringSubview(toFront: preferredView)
}
```

Then add your button action methods and inside them reverse all your views around however they may need to be like so.

```
@IBAction func otherViewAction(_ sender: Any) {
    view.bringSubview(toFront: otherView)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: preferredView)
    //do anything else you may need to do when the view is switched
}
```

[image]

This is one I've been working on

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how this should work.I can add the IBOutlet of container view to the viewcontroller. But how do I load the views?

Comment: The views load automatically when the ViewController with the nested containerViews loads. The ViewController class with the nested containerViews is where you make the containerView @IBOutlets and in this class is where you show/hide each view based on preference. You can further customize it by make custom ViewController classes for each embedded ViewController